# $P(A_k ∪ B_{n−k})$, for $k = 0, 1, . . . , n$

Tags: probability, statistics

An algorithm randomly generates a sequence $(c_1, c_2,... c_n)$, where each $c_i$ can assume the values $0$, $1$ or $2$. Given $A_k =$ {$k$ values of the sequence are equal to $0$} and $B_j$ = {$j$ values of the sequence are equal to $1$}.

How to calculate $P (A_k)$, for $k = 0, 1,. . . , n$?

I did this:

$$P(A_k)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.$$

How to calculate $P(A_k ∪ B_{n−k})$, for $k = 0, 1, . . . , n$?

I don't know how to calculate this.

Comment: What does $p$ and $q$ mean? Is $p=P(c_i=0)$?

Comment: $p$ is the probability of success and it's 1/3, q is the probability of unsuccess and it's 2/3

Comment: Well, $A_k=B_{n-k}$ Is not it?

Comment: @Phicar No. That would be true if the $c_i$ could only be 0 or 1.

Comment: @Milten Thanks, i didn't read that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the identity $P(A_k\cup B_{n-k}) = P(A_k) + P(B_{n-k}) - P(A_k\cap B_{n-k})$. Can you figure out the last probability?